# Javascript POST fetch to Express.js server returning 405 (method not allowed)

Tags: javascript, express, post, fetch, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to build an application with Node and Express, and in the script.js file I specify a fetch request to the API POST route I defined, which looks like this:

```
//Post to the database with a fetch request
fetch("/api/characters", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(character),
  })
  .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        alert("Error "+response.statusText);
      });
```

The route I defined in server.js looks like this:

```
//POST a character to the database
app.post("/api/characters", (req, res) => {
let character = req.body;

//Get the db.json file
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "/db/characters.json"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    if (data) {
        let charactersArray = JSON.parse(data);
        
        charactersArray.push(character);
    }

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "/db/characters.json"), JSON.stringify(charactersArray, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Successfully wrote character to db");
});

res.send("Successfully wrote character to db");

});
});
```

I tested the POST route in Insomnia earlier and it looks like it works, so I'm fairly certain the problem lies in the fetch request, but it looks to me like the path and method supplied are correct, so I'm not sure why the POST is saying that it isn't allowed.

Comment: Is the web page served on the same host:port as this API?

Comment: @Bravo I'm sorry, you may have to clarify; I'm fairly new to Express and haven't heard host:port before.  The server is listening on port 3001, and I am testing the fetch by using VSCode's live server, which shows the error.  Although interestingly, when I instead open with the URL localhost:3001 I get a different error

Comment: yeah, networking stuff can be confusing ... is it the same server process that hosts the web page and the API?

Comment: What URL is open in your browser? Is it `http://localhost:3001` or something else? Seems like you should be making a request to `http://localhost:3001/api/characters` if your frontend is served by something else (like VSCode Live Server). You'll want to [enable CORS](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) though